# Website tittle or website logo based on screen size

Tags: javascript, php, css

Hi guys i need some help.

I'm using the osclass script and have this code for the website tittle or the website logo.

```
<?php echo logo_header(); ?> <span id="logo_description"><?php echo osc_page_description(); ?></span>
```

Now what i try to get is when mobile size it shows only the website description (no logo) when bigger size it show logo description or logo header when uploaded!

Can someone help me?

Happy New year in advance!

Comment: use css @media to hide the logo and for larger screen show both

Comment: use @media queries when certain height gets show only this content, Here is the link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: don't work from when you upload a image there is no website tittle anymore

Comment: can also use some JavaScript